# Problems with two Webviews in two Fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-webview

I have a problem with 2 different WebViews in 2 different fragments. When I compile the app with the now commented out part of Code, and try to open it on my phone, it closes again directly. Android Studio Doesent give me any Errors, so I have no Idea why its notw working

Code of Fragment one

```
package de.thomaeum.thomapp10;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Frag_Unterstufe extends Fragment {

    public WebView webViewUnterstufe;
    public String pdfUnterstufe = "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + "https://www.thomaeum.de/download/thom_si.pdf";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_unterstufe_layout, container, false);
        webViewUnterstufe = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.oberstufe);
        webViewUnterstufe.loadUrl(pdfUnterstufe);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = webViewUnterstufe.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        webViewUnterstufe.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }
}
```

Code of Fragment Two

```
package de.thomaeum.thomapp10;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Frag_Oberstufe extends Fragment {

    public WebView webViewOberstufe;
    public String pdfOberstufe = "https://www.thomaeum.de/download/thom2.pdf";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vO=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_unterstufe_layout, container, false);
        /*
        webViewOberstufe = (WebView) vO.findViewById(R.id.oberstufe);
        webViewOberstufe.loadUrl(pdfOberstufe);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettingsO = webViewOberstufe.getSettings();
        webSettingsO.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        webViewOberstufe.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        */
        return vO;
    }
}
```

I updated the Code of the Second Fragment to This because in the First Version I had made A little misstake (I used the wrong Layout file):

```
package de.thomaeum.thomapp10;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Frag_Oberstufe extends Fragment {

    public WebView webViewOberstufe;
    public String pdfOberstufe = "https://www.thomaeum.de/download/thom2.pdf";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vO=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_oberstufe_layout, container, false);

        webViewOberstufe = (WebView) vO.findViewById(R.id.oberstufe);
        webViewOberstufe.loadUrl(pdfOberstufe);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettingsO = webViewOberstufe.getSettings();
        webSettingsO.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        webViewOberstufe.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return vO;
    }
}
```

And now my Phone is not Startting the App.
I looked into Logcat and it gave me this Error:

```
2019-09-24 09:02:06.274 27925-27925/de.thomaeum.thomapp10 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.thomaeum.thomapp10, PID: 27925
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at de.thomaeum.thomapp10.Frag_Oberstufe.onCreateView(Frag_Oberstufe.java:26)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:847)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2954)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1753)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2041)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1636)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7946)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:812)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
2019-09-24 09:02:06.275 27925-27925/de.thomaeum.thomapp10 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

XML Code of Frag_Unterstufe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/unterstufe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML Code of Frag_Oberstufe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/oberstufe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There must be some error. Check in the Logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean Project->Rebulid Project. it's happen sometimes.

Comment: I tryed that but It didn't Change anything

Comment: same code working fine my side, can you post layout xml?, look like you are not calling correct web-view id.

Comment: Done that, do you see an Error?